# API Structure for an application

Tags: api-design, directus

I would like some help to build something a la https://pokeapi.co/ .

I have a problem when I try to make the following structure:

```
"forms": [
        {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1/",
            "name": "bulbasaur"
        }
    ],
"stats": [
    {
        "stat": {
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/",
            "name": "speed"
        },
        "effort": 0,
        "base_stat": 45
    },
]
```

Directus works fine when I have one relation field such as forms (make a new relation field to forms, get Bulbasaur, done)

I would have build `monster` and the `stat` table, and I need to give a value to the relation field `stat` (in that case, `speed`) of 45.

I tried to fiddle around with Directus with no success.

Comment: Hey André – could you explain the issue you're having a bit more? It seems like you're not getting all relational data returned, but I want to be sure.

Perhaps you could write the JSON you'd like to get and what you're actually getting?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ < this is the closest structure I want to get and as you see in `stats` and many other fields is the goal I want to achieve, for one Pokemon, I want many stats that has its own value and these stats has its own table (with its own data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey André – it seems like this is more of a database architecture question. But here is a schema I would use:

- **monsters**

  - id
  - name
  - stats *(ALIAS: Many-to-Many interface relationship)*
- **monster_stats** *(Junction table for the many-to-many)*

  - id
  - monster_id
  - stat_id
- **stats**

  - id
  - name
  - effort
  - base_stat

Comment: Thanks for answering! Guess that`s how I need to create it!